# How to remove contributors in github repository?

Tags: git, github

When I work on team repo, I used another github account to commit to the private repo.

So I removed the wrong commit as git command.

As the result, the wrong commits were removed. But the repository still shows with two contributors.

How can I remove the wrong commit user?

Comment: What do you mean "removed it"?  Unless you have rewritten the git history to totally expunge the commit, it will still be there ... and the corresponding contributor will be there.

Comment: I mean I delete wrong git commit history and pushed again with my git id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove the contributors, they are still have commit history in your repo,

**contributors and collaborators is totally different.**

collaborators are contributors authorized by the repository owner to have direct access to repositor (without doing fork)

Comment: So you mean it's not possible to remove contributor in git repo?

Comment: @best-lucky1030 yes